# Object Required 424 Error only occurs in IE11

Tags: asp.net, internet-explorer-11

My Company has an intranet-site that uses .asp files. It suddenly stopped working properly in IE11. This particular snippet seems to throw an "Object Required - 424" Error.

```
dim fs,f


set fs=Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

set f=fs.CreateTextFile( Server.MapPath ("My/Path/to.txt") ,true)
f.Write( getList( strSQL_Sachnummer ) )
f.Close

set f=fs.CreateTextFile(  Server.MapPath ("My/Path/to/another.txt") ,true)
f.Write( getList( strSQL_SAPnummer ) )
f.Close

set f=nothing
set fs=nothing
```

The getList() sub, strSQL_Sachnummer and strSQL_SAPnummer are defined in the previous code.

Does it contain any errors? is it an IE-thing? It runs only in IE. Chrome, for example, doesn't work at all (maybe that helps)

Answer (score 0):

I might have found the Problem. VBScript is disabled by default in IE11, and can only be changed using a [group policy setting](http://%20https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/internet-explorer/ie11-deploy-guide/new-group-policy-settings-for-ie11). As I can't change those, I will have to find a different solution. At least I know it wasn't the code :D